# Addressing Objects in a JSON Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, pug

I'm sending a JSON array to a script for further processing. The JSON array contains a bunch of objects each of which contain a further array of objects. What I need to know is how to access values within those nested objects. So, for instance, if the script receives the following:

```
petlist = [
    {"cats":[
            {"catName":"Felix","catType":"British short haired"}
        ]
    },
    {"dogs":[
            {"dogName":"Fido","dogType":"Labrador"}
        ]
    },
    {"fish":[
            {"fishName":"Bob","fishType":"Goldfish"}
        ]
    },
    {"birds":[
            {"birdName":"Polly","birdType":"Parrot"}
        ]
    }
]
```

How would I then address, say, a) dogName, b) birdType, or c) the entire cats object?

Also, am I correct in my terminology here? As I understand it the stuff in square brackets is an array, while the stuff in curly braces is an object.

edit: I am building the JSON in Javascript and I then need to access the elements in a Jade template (in an 'each' loop)

Thanks

Comment: json.parse(petlist) in javascript will convert json into array.By array processing you can access any data

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking, as those will help you get more and better answers from the community. State the language you are intending to use this on (JAvascript will handle different from say, Java or C+)

Comment: edited to add specifics of where I'm trying to do this.

Comment: @Drum If I did not misunderstand your statement, then [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/NS96cm8btp1UKTjDNjkt) might be your solution.

Comment: Having an array of objects, each of which has a single key, is pretty useless. Just use an object which has all those keys directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed your JSON a little bit because I think it was not very fun to work with. Basically I just loop through the objects thats why I thought you should have a key like name instead of dogName, catName and so on.

You can find the working example with Jade in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/34BMe/164/)

HTML

```
<div id="jadeoutput"></div>
<pre id="jadeinput" style="display:none">
- console.log(petlist)
h1 List
  ul.list
    - for(var i in petlist)
      li= "Item - "+ petlist[i].name 
      - for(var j in petlist[i].pets)
      li= "Pet - " + petlist[i].pets[j].name + " " + petlist[i].pets[j].type
</pre>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    var json = {
    "petlist" : [
        { 
            "name" : "cats",
            "pets":
            [
                { "name":"Felix","type":"British short haired"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "name" : "dogs",
            "pets":
            [
                {"name":"Fido","type":"Labrador"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "name" : "fish",
            "pets":
            [
                {"name":"Bob","type":"Goldfish"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "name" : "birds",
            "pets" :
            [
                {"name":"Polly","type":"Parrot"}
            ]
        }
    ]};

    $("#jadeoutput").html(jade.compile($("#jadeinput").html())(json));
});
```

Comment: Anytime you see **{ braces }** in a JSON stream, that will correspond to an *object.* Anytime you see **[ square brackets ]**, that's an *array.* Once you successfully decode the JSON, you'll have a JavaScript variable whose internal structure exactly matches that. ("Yes, JSON *is* JavaScript ...")

Comment: And if he wants to add sharks he will have to change his complete code just to add them instead of dynamically looping through them. I know that I  could just use the names.